# How to find interval where function $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x^{3}}$ is one to one\injective?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

How to find interval where function is one to one $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x^{3}}$ ?(graphically or algebraically analytically)
 Let $f(x) =f(y)$ this gives $ (x-y)(\frac{(xy)^{3}-y^{2}-x^{2}+xy}{(xy)^{3}})=0 $

I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: *Hint:* A function $f$ defined on a closed interval $[a,b]$ is one-to-one iff it is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing on this interval.

Comment: Yes, monotonicity implies injectivity. So study the derivative and find intervals where the derivative is of constant sign.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint :**

$$f'(x) = 1 - \frac{3}{x^4} \implies \begin{cases} f'(x) > 0, \; x \in (-\infty,-3^{1/4})\cup(3^{1/4},\infty) \\ f'(x) <0, \; x \in (-3^{1/4},0)\cup(0,3^{1/4})  \end{cases}$$

Comment: So from here except at $ |x|=3^{\frac{1}{4}}$ it will be one to one

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f'(x) = 1-\frac{3}{x^4}$.  For $|x| < 3^{1/4}$,$f'<0$.  So, $f$ is one-to-one in this region (with $x = 0$ excluded), as you can see in the graph provided by @greedoid.

Comment: I would choose an interval where the function is continuous as well. Otherwise the discontinuity might give you some problems. If I would modify the problem to subtract $10$ when $x>0$ you might notice that an interval containing $0$ is not good.

Comment: The derivative can also be positive.

Comment: @Rebellos, I agree.  I just gave one example.  The important thing is that the derivative does not change sign.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a local maximum at $a$ and minimum at $b$, then it is injective at

$\bullet \;\;\;\; (-\infty,a)\cup (b,\infty)$ or

$\bullet \;\;\;\; (a,b)\setminus \{0\}$

[image]

Comment: Ehh, yes..................